# Jupyter extension for VSCode on Linux throws error when doing anything Jupyter related

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

After installing code-oss on Manjaro Linux along with the Jupyter extension for code and jupyter-notebooks itself, the extension seems to error when I try to do anything Jupyter related inside code. If I try to create a new notebook from the command pallete, it pops up a dialog saying this:

```
Command 'Jupyter: Create New Jupyter Notebook' resulted in an error (command 'jupyter.createnewnotebook' not found)
```

Code then tells me that the extension activation failed and to open the chrome developer console for more information. This is what the chrome console then says:

```
extension activation failed Error: Extension 'ms-toolsai.jupyter' CANNOT use API proposal: notebookEditor. Its package.json#enabledApiProposals-property declares:  but NOT notebookEditor. The missing proposal MUST be added and you must start in extension development mode or use the following command line switch: --enable-proposed-api ms-toolsai.jupyter
```

[Initial Pop-up error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Afj.png)
[Chrome Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI4Gr.png)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can solve that problem by inserting`"enable-proposed-api": ["ms-toolsai.jupyter"]` in the start settings of vs code. So press CTRL+ALT+P -> "Preference: Configure Runtime Arguments" then insert the upper line. After that restart vscode.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem and found out this is happening because of the open source version of code - OSS. It does not have the proper config in the product.json.

The accepted solution to add to Runtime Arguments unfortunately didn't work on Arch.

Easiest solution for me was to install code-features from AUR.

You can find more info on [arch wiki site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code#Command_%22...%22_not_found)

Or directly on [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/linux#vs-code-oss-issues) regarding oss code issues.

Comment: I am using Manjaro Linux, and the lennart9499 answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to add "enable-proposed-api": ["ms-toolsai.jupyter"] to the runtime of vscode didn't work for me on Arch linux. But when I started vscode from the command line using the argument "--enable-proposed-api  ms-toolsai.jupyter" the problem was solved. So I created a custom desktop launcher for this:

Fist, copy the desktop launcher to your applications folder

```
$ cp /usr/share/applications/code-oss.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/.
```

Then edit the new file:

```
$ nano ~/.local/share/applications/code-oss.desktop
```

Now add "--enable-proposed-api ms-toolsai.jupyter" to both of the Exec lines like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Code - OSS
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/bin/code-oss --enable-proposed-api ms-toolsai.jupyter --unity-launch %F
Icon=com.visualstudio.code.oss
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;application/x-code-oss-workspace;
Actions=new-empty-window;
Keywords=vscode;

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
Name=New Empty Window
Exec=/usr/bin/code-oss --enable-proposed-api ms-toolsai.jupyter --new-window %F
Icon=com.visualstudio.code.oss
```

I restarted my computer and the problem was solved.